# UItextfield with Input format

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have 2 question

**1) If textfield enter 10 digit , after just hitting 10th digit it call a function (myFunction), i have below code to fix length 10 digit,below code work when i press 11th digit.**

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 10

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    if (textField.text.length >= MAX_LENGTH && range.length == 0)
    {
      [self myFunction];//not working it works when 11th time key is press
        return NO; // return NO to not change text
    }
  return YES;

}


-(void) myFunction
{
// do my stuff here 
}
```

**2) My second question is regarding Credit card input format with multiple textfield.
i have 3 textfield in which i have to enter 4 digit each, below is my code working fine, but it also work on press 5th times(like change textfield box )**

[image]

in viewDidLoad

```
self.txt_box1.tag=1;
self.txt_box2.tag=2;
self.txt_box3.tag=3;


- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
     if ((textField.text.length >= 4) && (string.length > 0))
    {

        NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
        // Try to find next responder
        UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
        if (! nextResponder)
        {
            [nextResponder resignFirstResponder];
            [self myFunction];
        }

        if (nextResponder)
            // Found next responder, so set it.
            [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check My answer

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.text.length > MAX_LENGTH) 
    {
        textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:MAX_LENGTH];
    }
}
```

Comment: second part? answer

Comment: Question 2 is a continuation of the question 1, provides two ways for you: 1.Using a textfiled, every four automatic Spaces, and then put on the mask, like he was in the input to users perceive three boxes.

Comment: 2.  if (TF_TAG_ONE = = textField. Tag){If (textField. Text. Length > MAX_LENGTH){TextField. Text = [textField. Text substringToIndex: MAX_LENGTH];Nsstrings * subText = [textField. Text substringFromIndex: MAX_LENGTH];[the self textField_2 becomeFirstResponder];[the self textFieldDidChange: self textField_2 withNewText: subText];}}

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
NSString* fullString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

if (fullString.length >= MAX_LENGTH)
{
  [self myFunction];//not working it works when 11th time key is press
    return NO; // return NO to not change text
}
return YES;
```

Same for #2.

```
NSString* fullString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

if (fullString.length > 4)
{
   // any code
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: second part? answer

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for the textfields old text length.

```
if ((textField.text.length >= 4) && (string.length > 0))
```

should be

```
if ((string.length >= 4) && (string.length > 0))
```

This should solve both problems.